# Recommended overlapping community detection algorithms?

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Looking for overlapping community detection algorithm with following properties:

- undirected unweighted graph
- potentially overlapping communities
- good scalability to 1M nodes
- good intuitive results on simple hand-crafted examples, with tens of nodes
- choosing the number of communities: 1) automatic; or 2) as input parameter
- (optional) suitable for multi-threaded execution
- (very optional) weighted edges

I have examined the [BigClam](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/jure/pubs/bigclam-wsdm13.pdf), it looks good. BigClam multi-threaded implementation is C++ is part of [SNAP package](https://snap.stanford.edu/snap/description.html). I'd like to be sure that I don't miss better solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the link communities algorithm by [Ahn et al (2010)](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature09182)? Although you can't set a number of desired communities directly, you can choose a threshold that gives some level of choice.

Comment: No, I haven't. Thanks for your proposal.